# How to use requirejs on your client side code

Tags: html, css, node.js, database, requirejs

So recently I was making a website and I added a login page. I wanted to check if the username and password entered existed in the database and if not it would give an alert saying invalid username or password. My code is:

```
<form>
  <label>Enter Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username">
  <br>
  <label>Enter Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitLoginInfo()">
</form>
```

and the js is

```
const { LoginSchemaModel } = require('./dbconfig.js')
// import { LoginSchemaModel } from './dbconfig'
requirejs()
function submitLoginInfo () {
    let usernameElement = document.querySelector('#username')
    let passwordElement = document.querySelector('#password')

    console.log(`Username Element is HTMLElement: ${usernameElement instanceof HTMLElement}`);
    console.log(`Username Element is HTMLElement: ${passwordElement instanceof HTMLElement}`);

    alert(`usernameElement = ${usernameElement}`);
    alert(`passwordElement = ${passwordElement}`);

    alert(`username = ${usernameElement.value}`);
    alert(`password = ${passwordElement.value}`);
  }
```

Now the problem is with the require because that is not supported. So I decided to use imports instead and added "type"="module" to my package.json but was still getting an error in the console saying I can't use it. Then I used requirejs and ran into this issue where I couldn't import requirejs without using the require function. When I tried to add

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs')

requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require
});
```

it would say that I couldn't use require(). When I tried to do it in a seperate file I realized I had to require that file to use requirejs which wouldn't work. I have no idea on how to fix this, I have been searching stack overflow and other websites but nothing mentions this. I want to know if there is a different way which I have just been missing this whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are just declaring the js in some HTML with a script that will run in the client. Like that `<script src="./myscript.js"></script>`

#### Why you couldn't use `require`

`require` is the way we import modules in Node.js(an engine that runs javascript outside the browser) or any other javascript engine that adopts the [CommonJs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) pattern. Browsers uses what is called [ESModules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/).

#### Why did changing type="module" in `package.json` didn't solve this problem?

The `package.json` file is completely ignored by the browser, it doesn't affect anything in the javascript you import from the script tag. `package.json` is file used by node.js(and other engines). And `type="module"` is used in Node.js to use `import` instead of `require`, so wouldn't fix even if the browser read it.

### How can we import things in browser javascript

Firstly I have to say that browsers usually expect people to use some [bundling tool like webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). (bundler is just a program that transforms all your .js files into a single .js file) instead of importing modules directly, but if you want to do it only using a web-browser and nothing more you can:

1. Add the type="module" in the script tag.
   `<script type="module" src="./myscript.js"></script>`
2. Use something like [the live server extension of vscode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj)
   Because, browsers cannot give .html files to have full access to your files, so you need to simulate a server in a folder.
3. So now you can simple use `import {thing} from "./myscript.js"` that will work.

#### How to use the `require.js` lib in the browser.

I have to say that you shouldn't use it, it is used by people that want some packages made for node.js to work on browser. But if one would want to use requires only using the browser they would have to remember that when we do `npm i requirejs` it creates downloads it into the `node_modules` folder, so we would have to import from there. But again, you shouldn't do that to solve your problem. Stick to the `import`.